# Index of iteration inside NestList

Tags: list-manipulation, random, iterators

I have a list of `RandomReal`:

```
delta = RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}, 1000]
```

I want to add each element of the list to the corresponding result of a function iteration in my `NestList`, but I need some sort of index in the `NestList`.

I can't do it this way:

```
NestList[g[#, 3] + RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}] &, .5, 1000]
```

because the `RandomReal` list has to be predefined before calculating iterations.

What are my choices?

Comment: So `FoldList` seems the function you need.

Answer (score 2):

As Kuba said, `FoldList` is what I need:

```
FoldList[g[#1, 3] + #2 &, .5, delta]
```

Comment: Perhaps you would rather use `Fold` instead of `FoldList`.

Comment: `Fold` gives me the last item of `FoldList` if I understand correctly which is not what I need, because I have to `ListPlot` the thing after.